# OnMouseEnter rotate a transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate a poker card on Unity3D, so when the player clicks the card, the card is shown.

I read the documentation and so far I'm able to do it with the following code:

```
public void OnMouseEnter()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up);
}
```

Now I want to do it with a OnMouseDown() using this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i == 90; i++)
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up);
}
```

But so far it does nothing. The idea is an automatic rotation.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

piojo's answer works, but it doesn't start when you click on the card, but when you click anywhere on the application.

```
private bool isClicked = false;
void OnMouseDown() {
    isClicked = true;
}

public float rotationSpeed = 100.0f;
void Update () {
    if(isClicked) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

This code starts the rotation on event called `OnMouseDown`. For it to be triggered when you click the card, you need to add either 2D or 3D collider to your `GameObject` . Those can be found from `Add Component`-> `Physics` or `Physics 2D`.

I used public variable for the rotationSpeed, because the value of it can be tuned from the unity editor.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In game development, we normally make these changes in an Update loop or Update function, with one change per frame. The documentation for that function actually tells you what to do:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

The only difference is that you'll need to wrap the movement code in a test for mouse down, `if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))`.